# Use (network) graph as vertex

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, markov-chains

I have a Markov chain with graphs as the states. Basically how one network structure would evolve to another in the next period. To avoid confusion, I'll use the term "network" instead of "graph".

I could plot out the state diagram (stored in `proc`) using with the code

```
edgefunction[pts_List, e_] := {Arrowheads[{{0.005, 0.5, Graphics@{Blue, Polygon[{{-1.5, -1}, {1.5, 0}, {-1.5, 1}}]}}}], Arrow[pts]};
g = Graph[proc];
Scan[(PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeStyle] = Directive[GrayLevel[0.7], Thickness[PropertyValue[{g, #}, "Probability"]/100]]) &, EdgeList[g]];
Scan[(PropertyValue[{g, #}, EdgeShapeFunction] = edgefunction) &, EdgeList[g]];
g
```

so it looks like this:

[image: ...]

Now I'd like to replace the label in the nodes with pictures of the networks. I have strings (Graph6 format) that allows me to do this:

```
graphlist = ImportString[Import["../out.txt"], "Graph6"]
```

[image]

The entries correspond to nodes 1 through 8. I'd like to graph this in the `CircularEmbedding` layout as well (so that it fits into the shape of the nodes better).

I know it's something with the `VertexShapeFunction` but not sure how. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[3, {{1/4, 3/4, 0, 0}, {1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0}, 
       {1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}];

labels = Table[RandomGraph[{5, 6}, ImageSize -> 30, EdgeStyle -> Thick], {4}];

g = Graph[proc, EdgeShapeFunction -> edgefunction, VertexSize -> .25, 
   VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[4] -> (Placed[#, Center] & /@ labels)]];

SetProperty[g, EdgeStyle -> (# -> {GrayLevel[.7], 
        Thickness[PropertyValue[{g, #}, "Probability"]/100.]} & /@ EdgeList[g])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]